# How to override `File::SEPARATOR`

Tags: ruby, separator, pseudo-globals

Documents for [`File.join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/File.html#method-c-join) states that:

> `join(string, ...)` → `string`
>
> Returns a new string formed by joining the strings using `File::SEPARATOR`.
>
> `File.join("usr", "mail", "gumby")   #=> "usr/mail/gumby"`

However, the result below shows a different behavior.

```
File::SEPARATOR #=> "/"
File::SEPARATOR = "doge"
File::SEPARATOR #=> "doge"
File.join("so", "wow") #=> "so/wow"
```

Could anybody explain what is happening? Is there a way to override this behavior by setting `File::SEPARATOR` to another value?

I don't have a specific use case for this, nor am I looking for workarounds.. just curious. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define redefine the constant, all future Ruby code will see this new value.

However the implementation of `File.join` is in C which references the [C constant of the separator](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/file.c#L4403) which you have not redefined.

Any C code will [reference the original value](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/file.c#L5963) (that was set when the Ruby interpreter was initialized) whereas any Ruby code will reference the overridden/redefined value.

Answer (score 1):

`File` gives you a `FILE::SEPARATOR` constant which gives you the correct file separator for the OS, and also the `File.join` method, which seperates arguments with the correct file separator for the OS.

It would appear that -- despite what the documentation says -- the function does not use the constant.

```
2.3.0 :004 > File::Separator
 => "/"
2.3.0 :005 > File::Separator = "!!"
(irb):5: warning: already initialized constant File::Separator
 => "!!"
2.3.0 :006 > File::Separator
 => "!!"
2.3.0 :007 > File.join("one", "two")
 => "one/two"
2.3.0 :008 > File::Separator
 => "!!"
```

Given that you *can* change the value of a constant in Ruby, this is probably just good programming.

Answer (score 0):

`File::SEPARATOR` is a constant and you can't redefine it. In Windows there is also `File:ALT_SEPARATOR`. Maybe you can find the answer here: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/124904

Comment: That's not the reason because in ruby Constants can be redefined. It just throws a warning. Thank you for the useful link though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for Array.join?

```
["usr", "mail", "gumby"].join("doge")
```

It doesn't make sense to override the File::SEPARATOR, it's a constant that ruby "gives" you so you don't need to guess if it's / or \

Comment: Thank you, but I'm just looking for a explanation. The question was edited by a moderator and he made it seem like I was looking for that though. Sorry about that.

Comment: And my 2nd sentence explains it kind of I think. Just don't try to override constants, it's a bad practice anyway

Comment: I know that very well. Just was trying to understand how the ruby internals work. Thanks though.